# Updating a table made with a while - Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, sql-update

I'm having trouble with this update. I'm creating a table using a `select` and using a `while` (it displays 15+ rows). Some of the values can be updated, so here's the problem. When I write a value on the text and select update, it will only update the last value that the form detects in the table.

I create the table and display the values that I have in my database using this:

```
<?php
  $query_busqueda = "select * from servicio join venta on idServicio = servicioID join usuario on idUsuario = usuarioID where usuarioID = '".$_POST["idUser"]."';";
  $resuVenta = mysqli_query($conexion,$query_busqueda);
  while ($renglonVenta= mysqli_fetch_array($resuVenta)) {
    //$totalHour=$totalHour+$renglonVenta['horasSerMes'];
    $totalMH= $renglonVenta['precio'] * $renglonVenta['horasSerMes'];
    $totalMonth=$totalMonth+$totalMH;
?>

<td><input style="border: 0;" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $renglonVenta['idServicio'];?>" class='barra' /></td>
<td><input style="border: 0;" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $renglonVenta['servicio'];?>" class='barra' /></td>
<td><input style="border: 0;" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $renglonVenta['precio'];?>" class='barra' /> </td>
<td><input name= "hour" style="border: 0;" type="number" min="0" value="<?php echo $renglonVenta['horasSerMes'];?>" class='barra' /> </td>
<td><input name= "monthandhour" style="border: 0;" type="text" value="<?php echo $totalMH;?>" class='barra' /></td>

</tr>
<?php 
  }
?>
```

And I'm trying to update the values using this code:

```
$query_update = "select * from servicio join venta on idServicio = servicioID join usuario on idUsuario = usuarioID where usuarioID = '".$_POST["idUser"]."';";
$resuTodo = mysqli_query($conexion,$query_update);
while ($renglonTodo= mysqli_fetch_array($resuTodo)){
  $query_updateVE="UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='".$updateH."',`costoSerMes`='".$updateMH."' WHERE `usuarioID`='".$updateIDU."' and servicioID = '".$renglonTodo['idServicio']."';";
  //$resuUVE= mysqli_query($conexion,$query_updateVE);  
  echo $query_updateVE;
}
```

Finally, I'm using echo to see what I'm doing, if you can see in the quote below, it only gets the value from the last record in my database. "horasSrMes" and "costoSerMes" should change depending of the value of each text field in the table.

```
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '1';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '2';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '3';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '4';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '5';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '6';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '7';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '8';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '9';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '10';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '11';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '12';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '13';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '14';
UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='9',`costoSerMes`='4000' WHERE `usuarioID`='30' and servicioID = '15';
```

tldr; I want to update the values that my table has into my database.
[image: The table that is created by the while]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same names for the inputs on each row of the form. If you have multiple inputs with `name="idUser"`, the value of `$_POST['idUser']` will just be one of them.

Give them names like `name="idUser[]"`. Then `$_POST['idUser']` will be an array, and you can loop over the array to process all the inputs.

```
foreach ($_POST['idUser'] AS $i => $idUser) {
    $hour = $_POST['hour'][$i];
    $monthAndHour = $_POST['monthandhour'][$i];
    // Code here to update the row with `idUser = $idUser`
}
```

Comment: Hi barmar, i tried your solution (don't know if i miss something)
But when i did that it displayed an error "Notice: Array to string conversion". In this images you can see the changes i made.
http://postimg.org/image/doua3kvuf/  (UPDATE)
http://postimg.org/image/ybizowf93/ (FORM)

Comment: **all** the inputs need to have `[]` added to them, and you need to get the current element of every array similar to the way I set `$hour`.

Comment: It worked :D i changed the things that you said, and change idUser for idService (because this was what i wanted to list in the foreach)
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing update once:

```
UPDATE venta SET horasSerMes='9',costoSerMes='4000' WHERE usuarioID='30' and servicioID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Code will be this:

```
$query_busqueda = "select * from servicio join venta on idServicio = servicioID join usuario on idUsuario = usuarioID where usuarioID = ".(int)$_POST["idUser"];
$resuVenta = mysqli_query($conexion,$query_busqueda);
$serviceIds = [];
while($renglonVenta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resuVenta)){
  $serviceIds[] = $renglonVenta['servicioID'];
}

$query_updateVE="UPDATE `venta` SET `horasSerMes`='".$updateH."',`costoSerMes`='".$updateMH."' WHERE `usuarioID`='".$updateIDU."' and servicioID IN (".implode(',', $serviceIds).")";
mysqli_query($conexion,$query_updateVE);
```

Comment: The problem is that if you check the table not all of my "costoSerMes" and "horasSerMes" are 9 and 4000.
It should send the different values, like in the first row is 4 and 1000
the second 4 and 1000
the third 0 and 0,etc
Not always 9 and 4000

Comment: have You tried to do: mysqli_query($conexion,$query_updateVE) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));   ?

Comment: ...to which I had to make an edit. you used the wrong API

Comment: i used the code that you put, it's almost working the problem that i have is that you can only update from the last row and it changes all of the values from that colum. But it's suposed to only change that one value.
Is like if you had 15 products and you wanted to buy Xnumber things from product number 1. But in this moment this code is updating that i want to buy Xnumber of all the products.
http://postimg.org/image/meayjm4zb/

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the way you try to `update`. Your code is vulnerable for SQL injection, which should be prevented at any cost, for instance with the usage of PDO. Also, you have n+1 requests to the database server. I would generate this query with PDO:

```
"UPDATE `venta` 
SET `horasSerMes`=?,`costoSerMes`=? 
WHERE `usuarioID`=? and servicioID in (select servicioID 
                                       from servicio 
                                       join venta 
                                       on idServicio = servicioID 
                                       join usuario 
                                       on idUsuario = usuarioID 
                                       where usuarioID = ?)"
```

and pass the correct parameters to fill the question marks.